# Acquire patents' forward citation data from BigQuery by application

Tags: google-bigquery, google-patent-search

I want to collect data by `application_number` like this. The real application number is `CN 201510747352`.

```
SELECT c.application_number AS Pub, COUNT(p.publication_number) AS CitedBy 
     FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p, UNNEST(citation) AS c 
     WHERE c.application_number IN ('CN-201510747352-A') 
     GROUP BY c.application_number
```

But it can't work. The url is the patent page. Who can do me a favor? https://patents.google.com/patent/CN105233911B/zh?oq=CN201510747352.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that patent can be cited after it's status is Application  - so instead of using initial number `CN-201510747352` - you should use app/pub number when status is Application - Also you need to apply not only distinct counting but also excluding counting same app with -A or -B or etc. suffix - that is why you will see use of the regex_extract function

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  c.publication_number AS Pub, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT REGEXP_EXTRACT(p.publication_number, r'(.+-.+)-')) AS CitedByCount
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p, 
UNNEST(citation) AS c 
WHERE c.publication_number LIKE ('CN-105233911%') 
GROUP BY c.publication_number
```

with result

```
Row Pub             CitedBy  
1   CN-105233911-A  10
```

> ... If I only have the application data, how can I realize it?

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  c.publication_number AS Pub, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT REGEXP_EXTRACT(p.publication_number, r'(.+-.+)-')) AS CitedByCount
FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications` AS p, 
UNNEST(citation) AS c 
WHERE c.publication_number IN (
  SELECT publication_number 
  FROM `patents-public-data.patents.publications`
  WHERE application_number IN ('CN-201510747352-A') 
)
GROUP BY c.publication_number
```

Comment: If I only have the application data, how can I realize it?

Comment: Would you mind helping me further? Is it hard to be realized?

Comment: I find there are two application numbers in patent page. one is in priority applications and the other one is in Applications Claiming Priority. The data I gathered is in Applications Claiming Priority. Sometimes it cannot work out, such as ZA200803637A in https://patents.google.com/patent/CN100573476C/fr. Are there any way to solve the problem?

Comment: I'm sorry for finding something wrong about the order you edited. Take 201020059348 for example, there 8 Citedby , but the order give a wrong answer. What's the reason it happened?

Comment: link:https://patents.google.com/patent/CN201728346U/zh?oq=CN201020059348